# Turn off Message Pages after login?

Tags: templates, system-messages

Is there any way to 'turn off' the Message pages that briefly show after a login, logout, etc.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're only concerned about system messages associated with *login and registration*, [**FreeMember**](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/freemember) is a great add-on and does away with them entirely.

There won't be any flashes of "You are now logged in" etc, and it will also display any error messages inline.

Answer (score 4):

I don't believe. However, you can use a addon like **[Custom System Messages](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/custom-system-messages)** to customize those templates

> Custom System Messages provides an alternative to the the Specialty
>   Templates for ExpressionEngine. All ExpressionEngine messages,
>   regardless of type or severity, are filtered through the same group of
>   templates, which are only editable within the Control Panel. If you
>   use Subversion or Git to version your templates, the Specialty
>   Template are left out. On top of this fact the Specialty Templates do
>   not not parse other template tags, so embedding other templates, or
>   using tags from third party add-ons do not work... until now.

Comment: @Tad Ward, I just noticed that System Messages includes a (relatively new?) "option to immediately bypass successful form submissions and not display any template at all." This addition makes it a good all-in-one add-on for dealing with system messages.

Answer (score 1):

I think, you should use [Login Redirect](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/login-redirect) add-on.