# Is there a way to display inline Status & Error Messages?

Tags: ee2, error, status, system-messages, messages

I'm new to ExpressionEngine and I was wondering if there is a way to display status and error messages inline instead of on their own page?

For instance, it would be nice, if someone got their password wrong, if it didn't show you that on a separate page, but instead showed you that on the same page (similar to the way Drupal does it).

thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Turn off Message Pages after login?](http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/5617/turn-off-message-pages-after-login)

Comment: No, I'm sorry, I should have been more clear, I'm looking for a way to use inline messages universally (across all forms / pages). Perhaps with a template tag or something.

Comment: See the [answer suggested by Siebird](http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/a/5618/22) in that post: Custom System Messages. It doesn't move the errors _inline_, but it does catch all system messages and allow you to display the errors in a normal EE template.

Answer (score 2):

It depends for each scenario. For member registration & login with inline error handling, we have created a free plugin called [FreeMember](https://github.com/expressodev/freemember) which is quite popular.

There are also other commercial member plugins which provide inline error handling and more (e.g. custom member fields using any fieldtype) such as [Zoo Visitor](http://ee-zoo.com/add-ons/visitor/), [Profile:Edit](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/profileedit) and [Safecracker Registration](https://objectivehtml.com/safecracker-registration).

For each scenario you need to look for different plugins. For example, Safecracker (front end entry forms) provides inline error handling out of the box. Comment forms you will need to investigate different solutions etc.

Comment: ok, so there is no universal way to catch the EE errors and display them with a template tag?

Comment: No (that wouldn't be possible because its not something that's built in to EE). There are ways to customize that ridiculous error page or the text on it, but if you want to display the errors inline, you need to use add-ons for your specific scenario.

Comment: Another alternative: if you're good with javascript, you could capture form-submit, do the submit with ajax and, depending on the result-message, for instance show a modal or redirect after success. (edit: mediagirl mentions this option too :) )

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of a way to display system errors in a template tag.

But you can use the [**Custom System Messages**](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/custom-system-messages) addon to move system messages into a template. This gives you more control over customizing the errors.

If you have JS skills, there's no reason you shouldn't be able to submit your login form using Ajax and show an appropriate error on the screen. You'd write a conditional based on the action ID (`{action}`) in the template to handle login errors in a specific manner and all other errors regularly.

> This extension lets you define any 2 templates within your template groups to be used as the error page. You have access to all the usual variables from the Specialty Templates, plus two new ones {referrer} and {action}.